# read data from a file rjags

Tags: r, jags, r2winbugs, r2jags

My data file looks something like this:

```
list(y=structure(.Data=c(26, 228, 31, ...)), .Dim=c(413,9))
```

Let's say this file is saved as "data.txt".

If I'm working in 'R2OpenBUGS', it allows me to pass the data as a file with no problem:

```
mcmc <- bugs(data = "data.txt", inits=...)
```

But in JAGS, if I pass data as "data.txt", it says: "data must be a list or environment". What's the problem here? Also, if there is no way around it, is there a way I can read the data as list in R?

My model is:

```
model {
for (i in 1:413) {
    for (j in 1:9) {
        logy[i,j] <- log(y[i,j])
        logy[i,j] ~ dnorm(m[i], s)
    }
}

# priors
for (i in 1:413) {
    m[i] ~ dgamma(0.001, 0.001)
}

s ~ dgamma(0.001, 0.001)

}
```

Comment: you could try reading it in and assigning it . `dat <- dget("data.txt")` . then pass this to data= statement

Comment: Thanks! I didn't know about 'dget'. I'm not sure if its working right though. Because now I get another error:  "Attempt to redefine node logy[1,1]". An I think my model is fine, because its was working in R2OpenBUGS

Comment: Ah actually, why do you have two nodes called logy ?

Comment: I'm basically assuming in my model that the log of my data is normally distributed. So in the first line I get the log, and in the 2nd line I say its normally distributed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the [JAGS user manual](http://www.stats.ox.ac.uk/%7Enicholls/MScMCMC15/jags_user_manual.pdf)

> ### 7.0.4    Data transformations
>
> JAGS allows data transformations, but the syntax is different from BUGS.
> BUGS allows you to put a stochastic node twice on the left hand side of a relation, as in this example taken from the manual

```
for (i in 1:N) {
   z[i] <- sqrt(y[i])
   z[i] ~ dnorm(mu, tau)
}
```

> This is forbidden in JAGS. You must put data transformations in a separate block of relations preceded by the keyword `data`:

```
data {
   for (i in 1:N) {
     z[i] <- sqrt(y[i])
   }
}
model {
   for (i in 1:N) {
      z[i] ~ dnorm(mu, tau)
   }
   ...
}
```

Comment: Thanks! another quick question. How do you initialise multiple chains in JAGS. I couldn't find an example of this in the user manual. When I do "inits=init1", it works fine. But when I do "inits=c(init1, init2)", it says: "Duplicated initial values for variable(s):  m, s". Any ideas? (promise this is my last question! )

Comment: use `list()` instead of `c` ?